# Split datasets in weka

Tags: dataset, weka

I would like to splits datasets according to number of classes in Weka.
for example if the data contains two class labels for example Yes or No, here I need to split, in case three class labels, I need three splits and so on.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.RemoveWithValues -S 0.0 -C last -L 1 -V -i original.arff -o class1_file
weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.RemoveWithValues -S 0.0 -C last -L 2 -V -i original.arff -o class2_file
```

This can be achieved from Weka CLI. The examples assume that the class variable is the last index.

Answer (score 0):

you can visualize them with pre-processing window check [WEKA Explorer Tutorial](http://csed.sggs.ac.in/csed/sites/default/files/WEKA%20Explorer%20Tutorial.pdf)

and also [Classification and clustering](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-weka2/) if you have training data.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you also included some example code.